# show children nodes depending on selected parent

Tags: django, django-mptt

Hi i've been looking all over and can't find the answer to this. I have only 3 months experience in using python/django so excuse my dummy quesion! 
Im using django mptt to display a simple nested set navigation.

```
<ul class="root">
{% recursetree nodes %}
    <li>
        {{ node.name }}
        {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
            <ul class="children">
                {{ children }}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endrecursetree %}
```

this works fine - however i would like to show only children of the selected category (based on slug) and not all of them. 
Any ideas ???

---

i finally did it like this:

```
{% recursetree nodes %}
    <li>
      <a href='/{{ node.get_absolute_url}}'>{{ node.name }}</a>
    </li>
       {% if not node.is_leaf.node %}
                {% for c in child %}
                        {% if c in node.get_children  %}
                                {% if forloop.first %}
                                   <ul class="children">
                                         {{ children }}
                                            </ul>
                                {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}   



{% endrecursetree %}
```

in views

```
category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
child = category.get_children()
if not child : 
      child = category.get_siblings()
```

but it is a hack. has anyone got better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send down some information about what node you're in, and then it's a simple `if` statement.

Regarding how to send down the node information universally, there are a couple ways to do this in Django, and none of them are perfect. My preferred method is context processors: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Answer (score 0):

```
{% recursetree nodes %}
  <li>
      <a href="/category/{{ node.get_absolute_url }}">{{ node.name }}</a>                           
       {% if node.name == category.name %}
         <ul>
            {{ children }}
         </ul>
       {% endif %}
  <li>
{% endrecursetree %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
{% recursetree nodes %}
    #check if the node is a child node
    {% if node.is_child_node %}
        <a href="{{ node.get_absolute_url }}" >{{ node.name }}</a>
    {% endif %}

    #check if a root node is the current category
    {% if node.is_root_node and node.name == category.name %}
        {{ children }}
    {% endif %}

{% endrecursetree %}
```

Comment: If you provide code, then please describe *why* this code might solve the problem. *"You can try this:"* is not enough. Please [edit] your answer accordingly.