# how to collapse/expand a django-mptt list ideally using CSS and no JS in template

Tags: css, django, django-mptt

I need to collapse/expand a django-mptt list ideally using CSS (and no JavaScript) in my template:
Following guidance from http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/templates.html, I got a basic view, and have consulted the below SO posts:

[SO#6037469:show-children-nodes-depending-on-selected-parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037469/show-children-nodes-depending-on-selected-parent) only seems to work at the first hierarchical level(I'd prefer for this to be recursive down the list.

[SO#26334107:expand-collapsible-list-of-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334107/expand-collapsible-list-of-objects) threw an error:

> Could not parse the remainder: '==0' from 'node.level==0'

Wonder if someone could *please* post an elegant CSS solution to templating such lists in a collapsible/expandable format?